# Ciclos Fibonacci

Tags: bucles

el primero es este:

/*Determinar a cuanto es igual la suma de los elementos de la serie fibonacci entre 0 y 100*/

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,numero,x,y,z;

    numero = 11;
    x = 1;
    y = 1;
    z = 0;

    for(i=0;i<=numero;i++)
    {
        z = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = z;


    }
    cout << "La suma es: " << z;

}
```

este me da un valor erróneo si le coloco i = 0 da 377, si inicio i = 1, me da 233 y el valor final debe dar 232.

los otros son estos 2 que no tengo ni idea como hacerlos 
son estos:

/*Determinar a cuanto es igual el promedio entero de los elementos de la serie fibonnaci entre 0 y 1000.*/

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,y,z,numero,acumulado,i,promedio;

    x = 0;
    y = 1;
    z = 0
    numero = 16;
    acumulado = 0;
    promedio = 0;

    for(i=2;i<=numero;i++)
    {
        z = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = z;

        acumulado = acumulado + z;
    }
    cout << acumulado << endl;
    promedio = acumulado/numero;
    cout << "El promedio es: " << promedio;

    return 0;
}
```

/*Determinar cuantos elementos de la serie fibonnaci se encuentran entre 1000 y 2000*/

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int contador,x,y,z;

    x = 0;
    y = 1;
    z = 0;

    while(z<=2000)
    {
        if(z>=1000)
        {
            contador++;
        }
        z = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = z;      
    }

    cout << "Hay " << contador << " elementos entre 1000 y 2000 de la serie fibonacci";


    return 0;
}
```

si pueden explicármelos sin la respuesta para poder hacerlos alguna guía o algo(apenas estoy empezando en esto, he estado practicando desde noviembre del año pasado practicando, leyendo y buscando ejercicios, ahora estoy con los ciclos,dentro de 1 mes entro a la universidad y estoy practicando).

Comment: si escribis la serie de fibonacci, y seguis paso a paso tu codigo, te daras cuenta de tu error. porque z = x + y?

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para que la comunidad entienda mejor tu pregunta, debes leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Luego [edit] la pregunta.

Comment: hola haz tratado de hacer recursividad?    unsigned int numero;

    /* Generamos Fibonaccis */
    for (numero=0; numero<48; numero++)
      printf("%u\n", fibonacci_simple(numero));

    return 0;

Comment: recursividad? he leído sobre eso pero, aun no se como implementarlo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La sucesión de Fibonacci se calcula según la siguiente fórmula:

[image: fibonacci]

Existen dos maneras básicas de tratar un problema de este estilo: De manera imperativa o recursiva.

la estrategia iterativa se basa en ejecutar un fragmento múltiples veces en un bucle y modificar valores en cada iteración. Esta es la estrategia que sigues en tu fragmento de código.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
int t;
for(int i = 1; i < n;i++)
{
    t = x + y;
    x = y;
    y = t;
}
std::cout << y << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

En este caso, en la primera iteración del bucle, *x = 0* e  *y = 1*. *t* será 1.

En la segunda iteración, *x = 1*, *y = 1*,*t = 2*
Como ves, el bucle utiliza una variable auxiliar,*t*, para calcular el valor intermedio.
debes definir n como el número de iteraciones o "vueltas" que quieres dar al bucle, en el caso de tu ejemplo, *n= 100*.

La segunda opción es utilizar recursividad. Esto simplemente es llamar a una función dentro de ella misma.

```
#include <iostream>
unsigned long long fib_rec(int n)
{
if (n<2)
    return n;
else
    return fib_rec(n-1) + fib_rec(n-2);
}
int main()
{
    int n = 100;
    std::cout << fib_rec(n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Como ves,definimos una función fib_rec, que se llama a si misma, pero con los valores n-1 y n-2.
Como puedes ver, esto se parece mucho a la definicón matemática de la función y es bastante claro.
En el caso de que n sea 1, el código entrará en el if y devolverá 1, y en el caso de que sea 0, devolverá 0.
Por lo tanto, la ejecución de fib_rec(3), por ejemplo, sería:

```
fib_rec(3) = fib_rec(2) + fib_rec(1)
fib_rec(3) = fib_rec(1) + fib_rec(0) + fib_rec(1)
fib_rec(3) = 1 + 0 + 1
fib_rec(3) = 2
```

Comment: Logre hacer los otros 2 de la manera iterativa ayer en la noche, gracias por las respuestas, tendré que leer mas sobre recursividad que veo que agiliza mas el código aunque no entiendo mucho aun.Gracias compañeros.